# On calling JavaScript file from Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, getscript

I had written a calendar control in jQuery that I wanted to use in an Angular 2 project.

I've learned from other answers on this topic that I can use jQuery's `getScript()` API to call into external JavaScript files.

My `calendar.component.ts` looks like this:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit }     from '@angular/core';
import { Auth }                                 from '../auth.service';

declare var $:any;
declare var CustomCal:any;

@Component({
    selector:       'app-calendar',
    templateUrl:    './calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls:      ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

    private year : number;
    myCal : any;

    constructor(private auth : Auth) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.year   = 2017;

        $.getScript('./app/calendar/zapCalendar.js', function(){
            console.log("got call'd back");
            this.myCal = new CustomCal(2017);
        });
    }
}
```

I get the console message "got call'd back", then an error message stating that `CustomCal` is not defined.

My `CustomCal` class is defined in `zapCalendar.js` as follows:

```js
class CustomCal
{
    constructor(nYear) {

        this._mouseDown     = false;
        this._mouseDrag     = false;

        this._lastItem      = 0;
        this._nYear         = nYear;

        this.CreateCalendarFrame();
        this.AddEventHandlers(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

I've tried export'ing the class in the `zapCalendar.js` file, and also tried adding the following to the `zapCalendar.js` file:

```js
$( function() {
    var myCal = new CustomCal(2017);
});
```

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

I've just replaced this (in `zapCalendar.js`)

```js
$( function() {
    var myCal = new CustomCal(2017);
});
```

with this:

```js
var x = new CustomCal(2017);
```

And now the calendar is rendering correctly.  But I'd like (if possible) to get a reference to the calendar in my typescript.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.getScript('./app/calendar/zapCalendar.js', function(){
        console.log("got call'd back");
        this.myCal = new CustomCal(2017);
    });
```

The inner function here will not have the same `this` reference because it won't be called bound to your object. Since you're using TypeScript, you can just use an arrow function to change this behavior.

```
    $.getScript('./app/calendar/zapCalendar.js', () => {
        console.log("got call'd back");
        this.myCal = new CustomCal(2017);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't aware of that (new to angular).  But while my this reference may now be correct, I still get the error that CustomCal is not defined (in console).

Answer (score 0):

you need to export class then import it in your component

```
import {CustomCal} from "./app/calendar/zapCalendar";
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with writing modules.  When I preceed the CustomCal class with the export keyword and attempt to import, I get the message "Cannot find module './zapCalendar'.)"

Comment: there should be file `./app/calendar/zapCalendar.ts`

Comment: .ts?  But my zapCalendar is a javascript file.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that I need to rewrite my calendar ctrl in typescript/angular2.  is use of jquery frowned upon?

Comment: Note that Typescript is its own thing. You can write a Typescript file, and it can have nothing to do with Angular. Since your code is just a class, it shouldn't take an immense amount of porting work to be parsed as Typescript.